# Dual booting Windows 7 & 8 knocked out bootloader

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bcd, bcdedit

I recently have dual booted both Windows 7 and Windows 8 on the same hard drive.

Windows 7 was the first OS installed on the disk, but when I decided to install Windows 8 on a seperate partition, it knocked out my entire boot menu, so I cannot boot into my Windows 7 Partition.

I have looked at the BCD edit commands, and have sucessfuly managed to backup my current bootloader.

Now the problem is, how do I go about creating a boot menu so I can boot into Windows 7?

My current is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
integrityservices       Enable
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {f5c859a4-3053-11e5-b7ad-c982cabc92c8}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {f5c859a6-3053-11e5-b7ad-c982cabc92c8}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {f5c859a4-3053-11e5-b7ad-c982cabc92c8}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

And my disc management shows:

[image]

C Drive being Windows 8 and E Drive being Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8/8.1 during installation has created a new "System Reserved" active partition (350 MB) so the old BCD from Windows 7 should be still on the 100 MB "System Reserved" (D:).

The only problem I can see is that new "System Reserved" is far away from beginning of disk but as long as you can boot Windows 8/8.1 there seems no problem.

Solution:

To add Windows 7 to boot menu you can use [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) (use version 0.9.3.1)

Install and run the tool. Ignore message for BCD changed externally.

Right click on left where loaders are listed and select "Create missing Windows loaders" (or just use key 'F9') - this will add Windows 7 to boot menu. No need to specify any parameter as drive, path etc.

---

To fix "Repair your computer" on F8 key ==> when in Windows 7 use following two commands on admin command prompt:

```
ReAgentC /disable

ReAgentC /enable
```

This would make BCD settings for Windows 7 complete.

---

If you want to change Windows 8 boot menu display in old text style change the value of element "0x250000c2" (Boot Menu Policy) for Windows 8.1 loader to 0 (legacy).

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in getting back to you. This did work!  I did not know that you could switch to the legacy boot menu.. that shall be swapped over!.. do you have the same encounter where the keyboard and mouse is locked out for a few seconds on the windows 8 boot loader?